# automated J unit software test in java

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I have wrote but I don't know what is wrong, it should return sum of the values of arrays if the array is not-empty but if array is empty it should return zero.

```
public class Calculation {
    int findSum(int A[], int N) {
        if (N <= 0)
            return 0;
        return (findSum(A, N - 1) + A[N - 1]);
    }

    int main() {
        int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
        System.out.print("Sum = " + findSum(A, N));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: oh... maybe. i really don't know what is junit but what i know is this code doesn't run... please help me i'm stuck! ;(

Comment: @Storm47 You are confusing C syntax with Java. Also FYI, Junit is used for unit tests.

Comment: yeah sorry for that typing mistake i have changed this but it still don't run... it gives error of int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]); i really don't know what is sizof, but i have to solve this please let me know if it could run in any way... thank you.

Comment: @AymanPatel you are right I'm really confused just please correct this code for me...

Comment: Java has no sizeof function (in fact it has no functions at all that is not part of an object). You're probably looking for `A.length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using C/C++ code in Java. This is working for Java

```java
public class Calculation {
    static int findSum(int[] A, int N) {
        
        if(N<=0) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i:A) {
            sum+=i;
        }
        return sum;
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] A = {1,2,3,4,5};
      int N = A.length;
      System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + findSum(A, N));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @AymanPatel , it is running now but i don't know how to perform it's Junit test ... just help me and let me know how would i find this.... and once again thank you so much... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArrayUtils {
    static int sumOfArray(int[] arr) {
        
        if(arr.length<=0) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        int sumOfArray = 0;
        for(int i:arr) {
            sumOfArray+=i;
        }
        return sumOfArray;    
        
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
      System.out.println("Sum of all array elements = " + sumOfArray(arr));
    }

}
```

Comment: @Storm47 regarding test cases, are you using spring boot ?

Comment: I really don't know how to perform test cases... just tell me how to do this or do that test cases for me I'm really confused... please ;(

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle in yuor project?

Comment: @AymanPatel non of them :| ... by the way I'm doing a JUnit test in Netbeans.

Comment: You can import JUnit using JAR, but it would be better to use a build tool